# GNOME apps don't display correctly after installing NVIDIA drivers on EndeavourOS

Tags: linux, x11, gnome, wayland, endeavouros

I installed NVIDIA drivers on my EndeavourOS system using these commands:

1. `sudo pacman -Syu`
2. `sudo pacman -S nvidia nvidia-utils`
3. `sudo nano /etc/modules-load.d/nvidia.conf` and added "nvidia" to it
4. `sudo mkdir /etc/environment.d/`
5. `sudo nano /etc/environment.d/30-nvidia.conf` and added this "__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1" to it
6. `sudo reboot`

nvidia-smi works properly, and most apps too, except for the default GNOME ones
here is an example with the settings application:

[image]

Is this a known issue? I haven't experienced this error before, thank you very much for any help in forward.